# Callback function won't fire after sendResponse()

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to communicate between my background service worker and my content script but even though i added a callback it won't fire

**content.js**

```js
setInterval(function () {
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
            message: "is-playing", callback: function (counter) {
                console.log("Callback")
                console.log(counter);
            }
        })
}, 2000);`
```

**background.js**

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
        sendResponse({ counter: request.counter + 1 });
        console.log("send response")
        console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError)
    });
```

I tried to check for errors through *chrome.runtime.lastError* but even that didn't work

Comment: You're trying to send a function inside `callback`, it's impossible. Make the function a second parameter outside the object, see the [examples](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
    {state: "is-playing"}, function(counter) {
        console.log("Callback")
        console.log(counter);
    }
)
```

{state: "is-playing"} is the "message"
and function(counter) {...} is the "callback".

Since you send a message every 2 seconds let me suggest you to use [long-live connection](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/#connect).